# How to create an update on iOS

Tags: ios, patch

Hi i'm trying to create and distribute an update/patch for my app on app store.
Does anyone know how to made it in the best way?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a patch or pure update - you release a full version of the app with the changes you require.

Comment: You mean that i have only to re-upload my new app version on the app store?

Comment: After you apply for the new version, yes.  Then you wait for the review just like the first time.

Answer (score 6):

Apple does not have an interface for hot-patching production native apps, if it's a hybrid app many of the JavaScript platforms allow to upload new JS, so some functionality might be fixed / replaced / etc.
I have also seen more hardcore solutions like this one a [Lua script](https://github.com/mmin18/WaxPatch) that you can load and patch your app remotely (might be in Apple's gray lines)

We @ [Rollout.io](https://rollout.io) created an SDK that allows you to remotely hot-patch native production applications, you can read more on how [here](https://blog.rollout.io/2015/01/rollout-io-under-the-hood-how-we-patch-your-mobile-app-in-production/).

Disclaimer: I'm a Rollout.io co-founder.